# At least the following dependencies are missing

Tags: haskell, package, cabal

I am starting a project. my cabal file specifies

```
build-depends:       base <4.8, criterion >=1.0 && <1.1, memoize <=0.6
```

criterion is in the sandbox of current directory. 
If I check with `ghc-pkg list memoize` it will show.

```
C:/Program Files/Haskell Platform/2014.2.0.0\lib\package.conf.d: (no packages)
C:\Users\Song\AppData\Roaming\ghc\x86_64-mingw32-7.8.3\package.conf.d: memoize-0.6
```

memoize is globally available.

However, when I run cabal repl, cabal complains memoize is missing. Do I have to re-install the package in the sandbox in this case?

Comment: yes, the sandboxes are restricted to themselves, and you should not be able to access global packages from them.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you do. The purpose of sandboxes is to work independently of the user package database, not in addition to it. You can override this by adding back the user package database with the `--package-db` flag, but it isn't a recommended workflow.